# silyl ketene acetal vs Benzene, which compound has a higher nucleophilicity?

Tags: organic-chemistry

With the use of Lewis acid Aluminium Trichloride, which one would have a stronger nucleophilicity? Silyl Ketene Acetal (CAS:  31469-15-5) or a phenyl group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reacting with what electrophile?

In general the silyl ketene acetal will be more reactive, after all the Mukaiyama reaction can be run in Toluene  [Mukaiyama Reaction wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukaiyama_aldol_addition)

Comment: α,β-unsaturated carbonyl. 
yeah I think SKA will be more reactive. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer please accept it